# Google AppScript, The function ends when a WHILE loop ends and no further instructions are ran

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a ticket list in a spreadsheet and every ticket has an equipment assigned. The equipments themselves are in a different list in the same spreadsheet. I want to run a function that runs through the Ticket list and returns the line number of the respective equipment on the Equipamentos sheet.

It seems a simple task and I'm using a WHILE loop to run through the list until the equipment number matches.

I'm also using a custom debug function that writes down the logs in another spreadsheet with function name and timestamp.

The problem is when the condition is met and the equipment numbers match. I was expecting the WHILE loop to end and to keep running the function but for some reason the function also stops along with the loop. I receive no more debug messages after the loop ends.

````
function onEdit(e) {

  actualizarResolvido(e);

}

function actualizarResolvido(e){

  debug(arguments.callee.name, "START");
  if( e.range.getValue() == "Resolvido" ){

    debug(arguments.callee.name,"e.range.getValue() is "+e.range.getValue());

    codigo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tickets").getRange(e.range.getRow(), 4).getValue();
    debug(arguments.callee.name, "Code is "+codigo);  
    equip = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Equipamentos");
    var i = 2;
    debug(arguments.callee.name, "On line "+i+" code is "+equip.getRange( i, 1).getValue()+". WHILE condition is "+(equip.getRange( i, 1).getValue() != codigo));

    
    while( equip.getRange( i, 1).getValue() != codigo ){
      debug(arguments.callee.name,"Cycle "+(i-2));
      debug(arguments.callee.name, "WHILE condition is "+(equip.getRange( i, 1).getValue() != codigo));
      if( equip.getRange( i, 1).isBlank() ){

        return;

      }
      
      i++;
      debug(arguments.callee.name, "On line "+i+" code is "+equip.getRange( i, 1).getValue()+". WHILE condition is "+(equip.getRange( i, 1).getValue() != codigo));
    }

  debug(arguments.calle.name, "Machine found on line "+i);
  }

debug(arguments.callee.name, "END");

}```
````

Comment: Change your `return` to `break`.  But I would suggest your change your logic.  Rather than `equip.getRange( i, 1).getValue()` get all the values and then loop through the values array see this article [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: It has a return because it's supposed to end the whole function not just the condition. But that condition isn't ever called (as expected). I've also tried removing it altogether with the same results.